# Could not load type "app_user_registration" when attempting to add fields into registration form

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm working on a app in Symfony3 with Doctrine and the FOSBundle 2.0.

I have been trying to add two fields into my registration bar the **firstName** and the **lastName**.

[I have found this tutorial on how do do precisely what I'm hoping](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/overriding_forms.html), unfortunately after the first few steps (prior to handling) I realize I'm getting this error:

> Could not load type "app_user_registration"

The code I'm using is *exacly copied* from the webiste, only difference is that my class looks like this

```
<?php
// src/AppBundle/Entity/User.php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /** @ORM\Column(type="integer") */
    protected $carma;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     *
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Please enter your first name.", groups={"Registration", "Profile"})
     * @Assert\Length(
     *     min=3,
     *     max=255,
     *     minMessage="The name is too short.",
     *     maxMessage="The name is too long.",
     *     groups={"Registration", "Profile"}
     * )
     */
    protected $firstName;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     *
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Please enter your first name.", groups={"Registration", "Profile"})
     * @Assert\Length(
     *     min=3,
     *     max=255,
     *     minMessage="The name is too short.",
     *     maxMessage="The name is too long.",
     *     groups={"Registration", "Profile"}
     * )
     */
    protected $lastName;
```

**Same effect occurs when there is a variable named..."name"**

---

I have spend the last few hours trying to figure out.
There is what I have tried:

- Using the 2.0-master version tutorial
- [The answer form here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31720106/how-to-add-a-registration-form-another-field-symfony-2-7-in-fosuserbundle)

Everything else showed my output code as the **answer** to the question.

Could anyone help a poor soul?

As an addition, here are my other files:

```
//config.yml
/*...*/
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: AppBundle\Entity\User
    registration:
        form:
            type: AppBundle\Form\RegistrationType
```

---

```
//services.yml
services:
    app.form.registration:
        class: AppBundle\Form\RegistrationType
        tags:
            - { name: form.type, alias: app_user_registration }
```

---

```
//RegistraionType.php
<?php
// src/AppBundle/Form/RegistrationType.php

namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

class RegistrationType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('firstName');
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'fos_user_registration';
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->getBlockPrefix();
    }

    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'app_user_registration';
    }
}
```

Comment: This error isn't in your User entity, its coming from trying to use the alias you have setup in your app/config/services.yml in reference to your user registration form.

Comment: And did you do the form type stuff as well because that is where the error is coming from.  And be careful when you look for other examples.  The second link you posted is for an older version of FOSUserBundle.  Indeed, most examples you will find are outdated.

Answer (score 4):

You should use this tuorial instead (2.0.master):
http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSUserBundle/overriding_forms.html

You are using tutorial "1.3.x version".

For Symfony3 you have to make this changes:

```
class RegistrationType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('name');
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType';
    }

    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'app_user_registration';
    }

}
```

```
services:
    app.form.registration:
        class: AppBundle\Form\RegistrationType
        tags:
            - { name: form.type, alias: app_user_registration }
```

```
fos_user:
    # ...
    registration:
        form:
            type: AppBundle\Form\RegistrationType
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you have been trying to also follow the tutorials for extending the registration form. You most likely should have the following entry in your app/config/services.yml file:

```
app.form.registration:
    class: AppBundle\Form\RegistrationType
    tags:
        - { name: form.type, alias: app_user_registration }
```

Then in your src/AppBundle/Form/RegistrationType.php you should have the following function:

```
public function getBlockPrefix()
{
    return 'app_user_registration';
}
```

That is most likely where the error is coming from in your getBlockPrefix() method. Check your services.yml and compare to what I posted. I grabbed that from my own app which is working fine.

Comment: I have realised the issue, it was actually in my `getParent()` function, because it returned `app_user_registration` when it should return `FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType`.